# Sending computer audio output to multiple devices

Tags: audio

I'm looking to take an audio signal from a computer (1/8"), or multiple computers if possible, and *send its output to some sort of switch/audio box that would allow me to choose between different receiving devices* - say between headphones and a receiver.

I don't want to split the signal, and I don't want to send the signal to both at once, I want to be able to choose where the signal goes.

Is there a box that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:
http://www.guitarcenter.com/Behringer-EURORACK-UB802-Mixer-102331477-i1153481.gc?source=4WFRWXX&CAWELAID=29484770
This will give you more control over how everything goes in and out, but is not the best for what you describe.
This might be more what you are looking for, but it is only for one computer:
http://electronicsusa.com/mk5.html